# Angular tag inside html element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have the following angular code:

```
<div ng-repeat="creation in creations">
   <input type="checkbox" data-foobar="[[creation.foobar]]" [[creation.params]]>
   [[creation.params]]
</div>
```

That's it, the problem is that `creation.params` contains "disabled checked" or "checked" values, and it should create disabled checkboxes, but it does not. I don't know why, all checkboxes are unchecked.

Even though when I later display `creation.params` variable, it shows correct value:

```
disabled checked
disabled checked
disabled checked
checked
disabled checked
```

for 5 checkboxes - but all are unchecked.

What's wrong?

By the way, I have used:

`$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');`

Comment: Why are you using square brackets?You need to use curly braces {{ }}

Comment: `$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');`

Comment: I think you should be using `ng-disabled` and `ng-checked` directives for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do that would be using [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).

If yo uwant to have more control check [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) and model your problem as described, it will work. Use `ng-model` together with `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`.

Edit:

```
function isChecked(param) {
    return param === 'checked'; 
}
```

or directly in template:

```
ng-checked="creation.params === 'checked'"
```

Comment: How can I do that, if this variable is either "checked disabled" or "checked"?

Comment: You can create a function in your controller which will `return param === 'checked';`